# How does a relay or switch work with batteries or capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, current, switches, energy, energy-harvesting

I am charging my capacitor so it can act as a battery for a short period of time. I already did the calculations for the battery discharging and charging.

My problem is now that I have a load, I want to prevent current to flow to the load until the capacitor is fully charged (or to my required voltage threshold) so I can get maximum output power/energy. When the capacitor is fully charged, the charge controller stops its current flow and stops charging.

What kind of switch or relay do I need that can read, detect or sense my capacitor is full and then connect the capacitor to the load until capacitor drops below a certain voltage?

My load is a wifi module which I don't want current to flow to it and cause problems before I get the correct power or energy levels that are needed.

My Capacitor will have a around 56 Joules of capacity.
My Load needs 1.65 Joules for 1 second, then only 0.1 Joules/sec
This will get me around 6-15 Seconds of discharging til I hit my minimum voltage of the capacitor which is 0.9V.

I want to prevent any energy to go to my load until the capacitor is full.

Comment: As requested in your previous related question, please tell us what you're really trying to do. What problem is this circuit supposed to solve? Your solution may have a better alternative.

Comment: @Transistor I added some more information.

Comment: This is an [energy harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting) application, right? (making use of little bits of energy) You might want to add the energy-harvesting tag

Comment: What is the minimum expected interval between 1 second burst loads ? Can you define  the min:max time to charge 1.65 J from your source? or give datasheets and more details. Then give the Vmin for the Wifi. I suspect your source is insufficient voltage

Comment: Even if you could get 2V on the cap after a very long time as the D1 drops to 0, the power of 1.65J in 1s means 1.65W @ 2V or 825mA which means your Cap ESR (R1) of 500 mOhm will drop 412 mV and reduce Vcap to 1.58V.. Try again with better specs e.g. a Maxwell Cap 25mOhm

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I will use a SPV1040 charge controller that outputs 3.3V to charge my capacitor and maximize my 3V, 70mA solar panel.
I also have a Boost converter right before my Load, that boost the low voltages from 0.9-3.3V to 3.3V, 1-2A output to the load. This is just a simple diagram to know what kind of switch i need to connect and disconnect

Comment: It will be completely unstable unless you update your question with more accurate assumptions. The ESR is too high as well. I can think of a dozen parameters that will affect the answer. So pls think about it harder and specify everything. e.g. assumptions for ESR of Boost convert source impedance when driving 2 Ohms approx.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 R1 is my power resistor, not my Cap ESR. I didnt look at specific capacitors yet.. i probably should. but I want to maximize my peak current output without damaging my boost converter. With R1, I can get a peak current of 6.6A which is around 54.45 Joules from my capacitor. Then the voltage only drops 0.5V @ 3.3V for 1 second which still leaves me around 52 Joules left @ 2.8V which will be boosted to 3.3V

Comment: Pls update your question to correct  the errors and show calculations

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

A comparator with hysteresis can enable a switch device (power MOSFET, relay, etc.) when the cap voltage exceeds one trip point, then disable the switch device when the cap voltage falls below a second (lower) trip point.  The switch will remain off until the cap voltage exceeds the first (higher) trip point, and the cycle repeats.

The comparator device can be a comparator IC or an opamp.  It is important that all signals stay within the comparator's input and output voltage ranges.  This forum and others have threads covering comparators with hysteresis.

Comment: I think this is the kind of switch I was looking for.  I will look more into those forums! I need the cap voltage to be higher than 3.2V and enable the switch. when the cap voltage falls below 1.2V to open so it can be charged.

Comment: Linear Tech and TI have newer comparator chips (some CMOS) that will run on and work with those low voltages.  What is the power source for the comparator circuit?

Comment: I have a solar panel, but using a mppt to charge a capacitor as a battery.